# Why is compiler saying "Type specifier missing" when using struct variable

Tags: c, struct

Im studying C language and trying to learn some about Structs, I have this example below and Im trying to see how the struct memory allocation is composed. I have learned that every field in a struct is wordsized so that if not enough memory is used there will be empty memory spaces which should be seen in the example, but the compiler gives me several error like ***Type specifier missing***, ***Expected '***, and ***Type name requieres specifier or qualifier***. How come?

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[25];
    int id;
    int year;
    char material;
} Student;

int
main(void)
{
    Student talu;
    printf("Size of tAlu %d\n", (int)sizeof(talu));
    printf("name size is %d\n", offsetof(talu, name));
    printf("id size is %d\n", offsetof(talu, id));
    printf("year size is %d\n", offsetof(talu, year));
    printf("material size is %d\n", offsetof(talu, material));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you speak of size, but print offsets: `printf("name size is %d\n", offsetof(talu, name));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried compiling your code and got errors, so I ended up fixing it like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[25];
    int id;
    int year;
    char material;
} Student;

int
main(void)
{
    printf("Size of tAlu %d\n", (int)sizeof(Student));
    printf("name size is %d\n", offsetof(Student, name));
    printf("id size is %d\n", offsetof(Student, id));
    printf("year size is %d\n", offsetof(Student, year));
    printf("material size is %d\n", offsetof(Student, material));
    return 0;
}
```

This is with using GCC as the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you forgot the closing bracket:

```
char name[25];
//         ^^^   !
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed a bracket.

```
 char name[25;
```

It should be  `char name[25];`.

Answer (score 0):

`offsetof()` take the type which's member's offset shall be caluclated as the first parameter.

Reading man pages helps.

Answer (score 0):

**OFFSETOF(3)**: "The  macro  `offsetof()`  returns the offset of the field member from the start of the structure type."

The size of the filed is not reported but the position which they are placed within the structure , the `offsetof()` used because :

"the sizes of the  fields  that  compose  a structure  can  vary  across  implementations, and compilers may insert different numbers of padding bytes between  fields".